# Android Adding "values-en" folder causes "Couldn't resolve resource" warning

Tags: android, eclipse, android-resources

I have the next problem:

When I add a new folder called *"values-en"* and I move the *strings.xml* file from the default folder *"values"* to that *"values-en"*, I always get the next error:

`Couldn't resolve resource @string/my_string`

I have cleaned the project and refresh and the warning is always there.

Is there any restriction where I must always have a strings.xml in the device folder "values"?

Someone has experimented the same?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must have the values folder. To support multiple languages you can add the other values folders (values-en, values-fr, etc). 
In the default values folder you declare your strings in your app's default language and in values-en the same strings but with their english translation.

Comment: I have the "values" folder, which still contains the default _styles.xml_ file. I just move the _strings.xml_ file to a new "values-en" folder and I get the warning.

Comment: you should have the strings.xml file on all values folder. Do not move it, copy it instead.